# PHP class_exists does not find a class which exists in the code

Tags: php, class

In my PHP code, I have a class `MyClassV3`.

In another part of the code, one is testing its existence:

```
$class = 'MyClass' . $version;
if (!class_exists($class)) {
    // ...error is thrown
}
```

In the logs, I get the thrown exception where `$class = 'MyClassV3'`. Is it a `composer.json` issue?

What could explain this?

Comment: well, yeah, it's probably an autload issue, or a composer issue if you're loading a class from another repository. Start debugging there, if you have any info come back.

Comment: Can you create it?

Comment: Giorgio, it is from the same repository.

Comment: Do you have a namespace with the class?  If so, you need to make sure it's referenced.

Comment: As mentioned above, you must reference the full name space if it's not in the global namespace. `$class = '\\Name\\Space\\Here\\MyClass' . $version;`.

Comment: The class does not have a namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performing `composer dump-autoload` was the solution.